# JIRA6 REST API - HttpClient and HttpClientCache JAR conflict

Tags: java, httpclient, jira, apache-commons-httpclient, jira-rest-api

I used JIRA REST client api and am running it from java main program,

This is the simple code, which Try to hit the JIRA server (JIRA 6.1)

```
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        new Main().doIt();
    }

    public void doIt() {
        System.out.println("Start .. ");
        String url = "https://jira.com";
        String userName = "sdfsdfsdf";
        String password = "sdfsfsfsf";
        AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
        JiraRestClient client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(URI.create(url), userName, password) ;
        System.out.println("JiraRestClient created successfully .. ");

    }
```

Every time when I run this program, i get "ClassNotFoundException", there by I find the dependencies and put the JAR file in my LIB folder,

While doing so, I get strange exception which is the result of HTTPCLIENT and HTTPCLIENTCACHE jar files. Below-screenshot shows the lib-files in my classpath

[image]

And the exception which I get is

```
Start .. 
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.CacheConfig.setNeverCache1_0ResponsesWithQueryString(Z)V
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:155)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousHttpClientFactory.createClient(AsynchronousHttpClientFactory.java:53)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.create(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:35)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:41)
    at com.arun.main.Main.doIt(Main.java:22)
    at com.arun.main.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Can anyone suggest me on this Please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the correct Jar file that has this method. The jar file can be downloaded from the link below:

https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache/4.2.1-atlassian-2

**EDIT**
small clarification around this.. Even if your pom.xml doesn't have entry for this jar.. just add -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1-atlassian-2</version>
</dependency>
```